# excel Vba error 400 when I added sorting to the end of my macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I Have a relatively long sub that adds data to another sheet in a bunch of columns based on where its coming from. this part of the code works perfectly, however I wanted to sort all the rows in the table up to the last row that was added. the sorting code that I added on to the end works if I hard code what cells to include in the range, but my range will grow each time the sub is run so I tried to make the range include the variable I named for the next empty row (1MaxRows).

When I do this I get an error that says "400", in the past when I have gotten this error it is because i referenced the sheet or workbook wrong, but this time I didn't change any sheet references. The section of my code that gives me this error is as follows:

```
Columns("A:Q").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=range("A2:A & lMaxRows" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=range("B2:B & lMaxRows" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
    .SetRange range("A1:Q & lMaxRows")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I have tried changing the range codes in a handful of ways but I always either get an overflow error or a 400 error. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should qualify your Range calls with the correct worksheet, and you also have quotes in the wrong place in your addresses. For example:

```
Dim ws                    As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
With ws.Sort.SortFields
    .Clear
    .Add Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & lMaxRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
         Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Add Key:=ws.Range("B2:B" & lMaxRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
         Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
End With
With ws.Sort
    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:Q" & lMaxRows)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I've assumed you have properly declared and assigned a value to `lMaxRows` (and note that it is `LMAXROWS` and not `1MAXROWS` with a number at the start.

Comment: i used       lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     to declare lMaxRows. and yes i used LMaxRows, the 1s in my question were a typo

Comment: but when i put your code in place of mine it says you have 2 lines of syntax error within the 1st with statement

Comment: Sorry - I left a couple of quotes in when fixing your code. Corrected now.